# In Objective-C, how do I pass a property as an argument for a function and then call the setter/getter methods?

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad

The code is probably the best way to see what I am trying to do:

AcInfo.h:

```
@interface AcInfo : NSManagedObject {
@private
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *registrationNumber;
@end
```

AcInfo.m:

```
@implementation AcInfo
    @dynamic registrationNumber;
@end
```

AnotherClass.h:

```
@interface AnotherClass : NSObject {
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) AcInfo               *detailItem;
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet UITextField *registrationNumberTextField;

- (void)setDetailItemValueFromUIElement:(id *)uiElement forAcInfoTarget:(id *)acInfoTarget;
@end
```

AnotherClass.m:

```
@import "AcInfo.h"

@implementation AnotherClass
@synthesize detailItem, registrationNumberTextField;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];

    registrationNumberTextField.text = @"Test";
    // I expect this to set detailItem.registrationNumber to the value of
    // registrationNumberTextField.text (Test) but it doesn't change anything!
    setDetailItemValueFromUIElement:registrationNumberTextField forAcInfoTarget:detailItem.registrationNumber;
}

- (void)setDetailItemValueFromUIElement:(id *)uiElement forAcInfoTarget:(id *)acInfoTarget
{   
    if ([(id)uiElement isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        // This doesn't do anything when it returns!
        (NSString *)acInfoTarget = (UITextField *)uiElement.text
        return;
    }
}

@end
```

In short, I want `acInfoTarget` to call the getter `[detailObject registrationNumber]` and the setter `[detailObject setRegistrationNumber]` in the `setDetailItemValueFromUIElement:` function...

Comment: Your casts are wrong.  If you have an id*, that should be a NSString**, etc.

Comment: Well, the point is that I need to keep it (id) so that I can pass different types of objects.  In this simple case, NSString would work the same, but that isn't how the final routine will work.  In any case, even if it's NSString, it still won't work.

Comment: It doesn't work because you're casting it wrong, I suspect.

Comment: Well, that's my guess too...  Any idea how it SHOULD be cast?

Comment: Well, just to be consistent (without trying to untangle the logic of your code) it would be something like `*((NSString**)acInfoTarget) = *((UITextField**)uiElement.text)`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set or read properties by name using

```
// setter
NSString *propertyName = @"myProperty";
[object setValue:newValue forKey:propertyName];

// getter
id value = [object valueForKey:propertyName];
```

This is slower than using the normal dot notation, though, and it's frequently (though not always) a sign of poorly-designed code.

Also note that `id` *is* a pointer type, so you probably don't actually mean "`(id*)`".

Your code wants to look something like this, I think:

```
- (void)setDetailItemValueFromUIElement:(id)uiElement forAcInfoTarget:(NSString*)acInfoTarget {
    if ([(id)uiElement isKindOfClass:[UITextField class]]) {
        NSString *newValue = ((UITextField*)uiElement).text;
        [self.detailItem setValue:newValue forKey:acInfoTarget];
    }
}
```

Comment: Also note that this is called "Key-Value Coding", and Apple has tons of documentation about it! :)

Comment: Thanks!  This is probably what I'll end up doing, although I REALLY wanted a generic function so that I don't have to specify the string for every acTargetInfo.  Is there any way to get the method name as a string instead of having to hard code every possibility?  I.e. [detailItem.registrationNumber name] and have it return "registrationNumber"?

Comment: I am guessing you've only wrapped this in a function to avoid repeating the -isKindOfClass stuff.  I would suggest that it might be more straightforward to have a function that returns NSString or nil based on just the uiElement, and then set the property using the usual dot notation.

Comment: Seamus:  Thanks, but the actual function is a bit more complicated and works with strings, bool's, int's, float's, etc and consolidates the conversion in one place, so to avoid having to repeat the "convert from string to <type>, save to the managed object, convert <type> back to string (to update the UI to the actual converted value" process over and over (with potential mistakes) so I am looking for a more generic solution.  I could always have separate functions for strings, ints, bools, etc. but don't like that as much.

Answer (score 0):

Properties are just syntax sugar for a couple of accessor methods.  They are not, in essence, variables so you shouldn't treat them as such.  If you want to affect a property, then what you wanting to do is call a method.  So you should pass a id and selector parameter and not pointer to a variable type.

Comment: Well, I've figured out the accessor methods bit, but is there any way to pass the object which refers to those accessor methods so that I don't have to pass two different selectors (the get and set methods)?  It would be much cleaner to pass one parameter and get access to them both like I do through the object...  I'm thinking that this isn't possible and am probably going to pass the name of the object as a string and get the selectors in the function using NSSelectorFromString...  :-(